# Trouble with Sending JSON object over POST to Google Gears

Tags: php, google-maps, curl, google-gears

Google Gears provides a geolocation API that can take LAC-CELLId information and supply lat-long data.
The API is detailed here: [Geolocation API](http://code.google.com/apis/gears/geolocation_network_protocol.html)
I am using PHP. Here's the code that I wrote:

```
<?php
$urlstring="http://www.google.com/loc/json";
$ch=curl_init($urlstring);

$cell_towers = array();
$row=new stdClass();
$row->location_area_code=3311;
$row->mobile_network_code=71;
$row->cell_id=32751;
$row->mobile_country_code=404;
$cell_towers[]=$row;    
$param = array(
      'host'=> 'localhost',
      'version' => '1.1.0', 
      'request_address' => true,
      'cell_towers' => $cell_towers
    );

$param_json=json_encode($param);    
//echo $param_json."<br />";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,urlencode($param_json));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("application/jsonrequest"));
$result=curl_exec($ch);
echo $result;
```

?>

The response that I am getting is "JSON parsing error."
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't urlencode. application/json bodies are *never* urlencoded.

Comment: Shit! Thanks a lot man, this was driving me nutz. Removing urlencode fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have the correct application type.  Their API uses: application/json

Comment: I changed that line to `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json"));` Still the same error persists.

Comment: I suggest you look at the JSON being generated, e.g. alert($param_json).  The $cell_towers is supposed to be [{stuff:stuff},{stuff:stuff}].

Comment: The [] comes in only if I have more than 1 set of values for cell towers. If I modify my code to add another set of values, then the JSON generated is:`{
 "host":"localhost",
 "version":"1.1.0",
 "request_address":true,
 "cell_towers":
 [
  {
   "location_area_code":3311,
   "mobile_network_code":71,
   "cell_id":32751,
   "mobile_country_code":404
  },
  {
   "location_area_code":3311,
   "mobile_network_code":71,
   "cell_id":32752,
   "mobile_country_code":404
  }
 ]
}`

Comment: Ok. Stackoverflow is making the code pretty much unreadable. So, here's the pastebin link: [link](http://pastebin.com/d09Mt4uJ)