# How to Get Lat-Long Data from LAC-CELLId using php?

Tags: cellid, gears

I am trying to get lat-long from cellid and LAC.

I have been trying to use this script mentioned in [Trouble with Sending JSON object over POST to Google Gears](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5715667/trouble-with-sending-json-object-over-post-to-google-gears/6368442#6368442) to accomplish this

Can you please point out any error if any or any alternate way?

I am pasting the code below

```
<?php
$urlstring="http://www.google.com/loc/json";
$ch=curl_init($urlstring);

$cell_towers = array();
$row=new stdClass();
$row->location_area_code=3311;
$row->mobile_network_code=71;
$row->cell_id=32751;
$row->mobile_country_code=404;
$cell_towers[]=$row;    
$param = array(
  'host'=> 'localhost',
  'version' => '1.1.0', 
  'request_address' => true,
  'cell_towers' => $cell_towers
);

$param_json=json_encode($param);    

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$param_json);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("application/json"));
$result=curl_exec($ch);
echo $result;
?>
```

This is the code after making the change(of removing url_encode)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your code is identical to mine, the only line where it differs is:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json"));
```

This bit of code uses CURL. Have you enabled the CURL library? It is disabled by default in most PHP installations.

Comment: I checked it,CURL is enabled But still it returns null -> {}. Do u get the results?

Comment: It turned out lac and cellid data was invalid. Have you tested it with multiple cell towers as well? Does it work?

Comment: Oh yeah, the lac-cell id values given are random stuff. I didn't need to test is for multiple cell towers at one go, as it wasnt in my requirements. However, I think that if you keep adding new cell towers to the array by creating new rows, it should work.